# How to subtarct 6 hours from time in beanshell

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I am saving response from my application using jmeter and i want to subtract 6 hours from that time using beanshell post processor.

```
   String timeforrequest = vars.get("response time");
```

time we are receiving is in following format

```
   "2013-10-26 09:36:00 AM "
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular java code in a beanshell processor.

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

String inputDateString = vars.get("response time"); //in the format "2013-10-26 09:36:00 AM "
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a ");
DateTime time = formatter.parseDateTime(inputDateString);
DateTime newtime = time.minusHours(6);
vars.put("newtime", newtime.toString());
```

You can download joda-time jar from m2 repository [here](http://central.maven.org/maven2/joda-time/joda-time/2.8.1/joda-time-2.8.1.jar).

Comment: thanks @RaGe but i am getting following error ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter; import java.time.LocalDateTime; impor . . . '' : Error in method invocation: Method info( java.time.LocalDateTime ) not found in

Comment: yes i am using java 8,sorry should have mentioned before

Comment: Hmm, you need to provide the java jars containing `java.time` package to jmeter, by copying it to `lib/ext` folder. Except I'm not sure which JRE jar contains `java.time`. I'm changing my answer to use joda-time. You have to place a joda-time jar in `lib/ext` folder for this to work.

Comment: still getting error Typed variable declaration : Method Invocation formatter.parseDateTime

Comment: You're getting an exception on the parse line in both my answer and @Dmitri T 's answer. Clearly the datetime pattern you gave us in your question does not match the string you're trying to parse.

Comment: sorry it was 10/26/2013 9:36:00 AM so i changed MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a " but still its not working.

Answer (score 1):

Sample code:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;


String timeforrequest = vars.get("response time");
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a");
Date before = sdf.parse(timeforrequest);
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(before);
cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, -6);
Date after = cal.getTime();
String newtimeforrequest = sdf.format(after);
log.info("\n\n" + newtimeforrequest + "\n");
```

Demo:

[image: Beanshell Time Manipulation]

References:

- [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class JavaDoc - I cannot guarantee that code will work for all date and time values as format may be different for systems with clock starting with 0 and with 1, etc. You may have to amend my SimpleDateFormat pattern
- [Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) and [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) classes JavaDocs - for more information on methods used
- [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) - for general information on using Beanshell scripting in JMeter tests.

Comment: getting this error:Typed variable declaration : Method Invocation sdf.parse

Comment: also want to mention that i am using beanshell post processor as i am getting responsetime value from other sampler

Comment: Than your `response time` variable value either is not set or does not match the pattern of `2013-10-26 09:36:00 AM`. My code assumes `response time`, mind the space between "response" and "time"

Comment: sorry it was 10/26/2013 9:36:00 AM so i changed MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a " but still its not working.

Comment: You've got everything you need to figure out the correct code by yourself. I cannot guarantee working solution if you cannot even copy-paste a part of response